# Problems with Pop Window

Tags: android, popupwindow

I do not want to dismiss the pop up window, when touched outside. I added these codes:

```
        popUPWindow.setTouchable(true);
        popUPWindow.setFocusable(false);
```

Now the pop up doesn't get dismmissed when I touch outside. But The problem is I have a viewpager. So When I swipe the page, pop up should be dismiised. I dismissed it by callin g dismiss method of the pop manually. But problem is when I scroll the page up, if popup is visible, it moves to the top of the page. I want it to remain in its place, when I scroll the page up. What can I do to avoid this problem.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try this setOutsideTouchable(true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Position of Pop-up Window try this following method.

**public void showAtLocation (View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)**

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I doesn't want it to be dismissed when I touch outside. It should remain even if i touch outside. And it's working. Only problem what I'm facing is when I scroll up, pop also goes to top. I want it to remain in its position.

Comment: @SangeethaPinto:You write such like that..I want to dismiss the pop up window, when touched outside..so i provide this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
popUPWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popUPWindow.setFocusable(false);
```